# vc++ debug : the application failed to start because ACE.dll was not found

Tags: visual-c++

I've used ACE.lib in my program and it compiled properly. But when I debug I get this error. The ACE.dll is in the same folder as the lib and I've also tried adding it to the project and PATH. Nothing works

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Verify that it really is in your path by:

1. Press START->Run
2. Enter "cmd" and press ENTER
3. Enter "echo %path" and press ENTER
4. Verify that the directory is there.

Your project directory is your running directory (unless you changed it in the project settings). Check what happens if you put the DLL there.

Lastly, try running your project executable directly (double-click on it in Windows Explorer, for example) while the ACE.dll is in the path or in your running directory.